# Do we know when $supp(\mu_y)= h^{-1}(\{y\})$, for a regular conditional conditional probability $\mu$ with regard to $h$?

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability

The situation:
Let $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces equipped with Borel probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $\nu=h_*\mu$ is the push forward measure with regard to a continuous (measurable) function $h:X\to Y$.

It is commonly known that in this case $\mu_y(\cdot)=\mu(\cdot\vert h=y)$ is a regular conditional probability with regard to $h$. So
$$
\int_A \mu_y(\cdot)d\nu=\mu(\cdot\cap h^{-1}(A))
$$
It is also known that for the fiber measures $\mu_y(h^{-1}(\{y\}))=1$.
Assume that we also know the support of the fiber measures $supp(\mu_y)$ is finitely bounded(
$\#supp(\mu_y)<n$). Obviously $\mu_y$ is the sum of weighted dirac measures in this case and $supp(\mu_y)\subseteq h^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Are there any conditions on anything such that we can force $supp(\mu_y)= h^{-1}(\{y\})$ $\nu$-almost surely?
Do we have any additional properties of the fiber measures?

Comment: Some observations: (1) I think you meant to say that there exists a regular conditional probability $\mu_y(\cdot)=\mu(\cdot|h=y)$ in the beginning of your second paragraph. (2) Is the assumption that $\#\operatorname{supp}(\mu_y)\leq n$ for all $y$? (3) For your question, a necessary condition would be that $h^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed for all $y$.

Comment: Thank you. (1) yes of course, I corrected it (2)no only $\nu$-a.s. (3) thats a good point. If the fiber is also of finite cardinality this would be the case. I have since noticed that the question I posed here might be to general.